# [firebase_ui_auth], How customize design of SignInScreen widget elements in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase_ui_auth package for signin and signup parts of my app.
in Documentation, there is given SignInScreen widget, which covers all email sign in/sign up cases.It's working so far fine.
But i cannot edit it as i want.
For ex: Button colors, and designs. Password input field visibility toggle, error message etc.

How can i change them? or there is any other alternative widgets?